# Not able to load static files in django template

Tags: python, css, django, django-staticfiles, django-3.0

#### **First off, I know there are many more questions like this in StackOverflow. But none of them seem to work. So here goes...**

I am learning django through this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhJIMUMJ_Do&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ib4HsrXEYpQnTOTZE1x0uc&index=12). The tutorial is kind of old but most of the code is the same. I tried adding some `CSS` files to the project just like the tutorial but for some reason, it is not working for me. here is my file structure...

```
src
    ├── assets
    │   └── css
    │       ├── base_styles.css
    │       └── index_styles.css
    ├── core
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── views.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── asgi.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    ├── test_app
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── test_app
    │   │       └── test_app_home.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    └── templates
        ├── aboutpage.html
        ├── base.html
        └── homepage.html
```

***Please note that `src` is the root folder. `core` is the name of the project and `test_app` is the name of the application***

The global templates reside under the `src/templates/`. The `src/assets/css/` contains the css files for the global templates.

This is my `settings.py` code

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

...
...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STAITCFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
)
```

this is my `core/urls.py` file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('test_app/', include('test_app.urls')),

    path('about', views.aboutpage),
    path('', views.homepage),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

this is my `base.html` file.

```
{% load static %}

...
...

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base_styles.css' %}">

...
...
```

I did everything the tutorial does. I am not sure why this does not work. Could it be because of the fact that the tutorial is kind of **old** and I am using `django 3.0.4`? The only difference I could make between the two versions is using `{% load static %}` instead of `{% load staticfiles %}`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Django 1.11.6 -> 3.0.4 is huge
Try reading docs, that's the best thing you can try for proper understanding:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: @Shashank, I scanned the docs for an answer to this problem. Nothing seems to work. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

in development mode add a static_root also:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn')
```

then collect your files

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

also your browser can effect so try to run incognito or stealth mode.

In the official docs,they serve staticfiles as below

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: what exactly is `static_cdn` here?

Comment: it is an example folder name, you can choose any name over there.

Comment: this does not work for me. I tried both `static` as well as `assets` in `STATIC_ROOT`. Both are not working. Also, I checked the docs. I found `from django.conf.urls.static import static`. But even this does not work.

Comment: I added the folders according to the video tutorial. So I guess I am in the right folder. Do you want to check the video to see where I am going wrong?

Comment: what is your templates DIR settings

Comment: the global templates reside under `src/templates/`. The css files for these templates reside under `src/assets/css/`. This is the code for templates in settings. `'DIRS': ['templates'],`

Comment: no in settings.py did you add a dir for your templates?

Comment: yes I did. Please check the question. I have added it

Comment: it must be in the format os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"), after that check your static files or any errors? and what do you see in developer tools 404  or any other error?

Comment: Yes. I get this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. for `base_styles.css`. The HTML templates load properly. It is only the css that is not loading

Comment: did you copy assets folder inside/under core app ?

Comment: the assets folder is outside the `core` app. It is in the same folder the core app resides

Comment: ok if you try like that, I suppose it will work.  then we will have to arrange another setting for your static folder.

Comment: I am still not able to resolve the issue. What am I doing wrong? I also scanned the django docs for the static fils. I am not able to find an answer to this problem

Comment: Hi! just saw the edit you made to your answer. I tried this already. This does not work for me

Comment: add static_root and python manage.py collectstatic. after that if that does not solve please copy your files under the same level with settings.py. if it changes one more setting to edit.

Comment: I have checked everything, there does not seem to be any bug. Only browser cache seems to be left.

Comment: You know what. I am just going to delete the project and start over again

Comment: happened to me once, I had to restart once because of a similar bug.